# unable to read json data in Jquery code in Laravel 5.2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to populate second dropdown based on value selected in first dropdown in Laravel.

[image]

When Cinema Hall is selected , it should populate screen dropdown , so I have used here ajax for doing so.

My code is below

HTML code

```
 <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Cinema Hall
                                <span class="required" aria-required="true"> * </span>
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                {!! Form::select('cinema_id',$cinemahall,Null,array('class'=>'bs-select form-control','aria-invalid'=>'false','id'=>'cinemahall')) !!}
                            </div>

                        </div>

                       <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Screen
                                <span class="required" aria-required="true"> * </span>
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                {!! Form::select('screen_id',[],Null,array('class'=>'bs-select form-control','aria-invalid'=>'false','id'=>'screenname')) !!}
                            </div>

                        </div>
```

Jquery code

```
 <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#cinemahall").change(function(){

                    var cinema_id=$("#cinemahall option:selected").val();
                    //ajax
                    $.get('/askspidy/admin/showtime/getscreen/' + cinema_id, function(data){
                        $("#screenname").empty();
                        // console.log(data);

                        $.each(data,function(index,screenobj){
                            $("#screenname").append('<option value="' +screenobj.screen_id + '">' +screenobj.name +'</option>');

                        });
                    });
                });
            });
    </script>
```

Routes

```
 Route::get('/admin/showtime/getscreen/{id}','Admin\ShowtimeController@getscreen');
```

controller function

```
  public function getscreen($id)
{
    $screens=Movies_screen::where('cinema_id',$id)->get();
    return response()->json($screens);
}
```

I checked in Console.log(data) its showing proper data no problem

[image]

But dropdown is populating like this

[image]

help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your should replace `screenobj.name` with `screenobj.screen_name` as shown in your response preview.

```
$("#screenname").append('<option value="' +screenobj.screen_id + '">' +screenobj.screen_name +'</option>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `name` to `screen_name` : `screenobj.screen_name`

```
$("#screenname").append('<option value="' +screenobj.screen_id + '">' +screenobj.screen_name +'</option>');
```

Answer (score 0):

ohhh I am so stupid spent hours figuring out the problem, i changed screenobj.name to screenobj.screen_name and it worked...